# Evaluation of $\int_C{F.dr}$

Tags: vector-analysis

For a given vector field and curve C, evaluate $\int_C \mathbf{F.dr}$

$\mathbf{F}(x,y)= -y \mathbf{i} +x \mathbf{j}$, C:Ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}$=1

First we parametrise

$x=2\cos{t}$; $dx=-2\sin{t}$

$y=3\sin{t}$; $dy=3\cos{t}$

Then we write a proper integrand

The limits are found by replacing $x=2$ and $x=-2$ in $x=2\cos{t}$

$\int_{\pi}^{0}{6\sin^2{t}+6\cos^2{t}}$=
$\int_{\pi}^{0}{6}=-6\pi$

But the answer is $12\pi$

Comment: You paramtrized **a circle** of radius $\;2\;$ , not an ellipse...! BTW, I am guessing the ellipse's *equation* is missing the $\;=1\;$ on the right.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it now, but it s still the same.

Comment: If you go around the whole ellipse the parametrization must be $\;0\le t\le 2\pi\;$ ...

Comment: You may also try the following tool for integral you evaluated: http://um.mendelu.cz/maw-html/index.php?lang=en&form=lineintegral . Agree with Joanpemo, you have a mistake in limits.

Comment: @robert.marik.cz Sites like the one you linked can be helpful to verify things, but not to *learn how to do things* .

Comment: @robert.marik.cz, Thanks for this one. I agree, it will not make me learn new things, but can be quite helpful for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 3):

Parametrize *the ellipse* :

$$\gamma(t)=(x(t),\,y(t))\;,\;\;\begin{cases}x=2\cos t\\{}\\y=3\sin t\end{cases}\;,\;\;0\le t\le2\pi\;\;\implies$$$${}$$

$$\int_CF\cdot dr=\int_0^{2\pi}F(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\;dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-3\sin t,\,2\cos t\right)\cdot\left(-2\sin t,\,3\cos t\right)dt=$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}6(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)\;dt=6\int_0^{2\pi}dt=12\pi$$